# How to map data in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, api

When I write `items.map` it gives me *items.map is not a function*. I am doing it for wishlist, taking data from `localStorage`, but I can't `map` it.

how can i map this data for write `x.id` for example

```
items?.map((x)=>{console.log(x.id)})
```

is not working.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Wishlist = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const items = localStorage.getItem('liked');
    items?.map((x) => {
      console.log(x.id);
    });

    console.log('items', items);
  });

  return <div className="test">hello world</div>;
};

export default Wishlist;
```

`console.log('items', items);` is working. I can see `[{ my all data},{like this},{there everything good}]`

Comment: Are you sure that items is an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Returned data from local storage is mostly string (or whatever it is, it's not an array) so logically that you cannot use array methods (not just map)

So to solve this problem you need to parse the data and by this, you can iterate over it.

### a code that demonstrates how to parse it

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I lost my 2 days for it.. You saved my life! I just needed JSON.parse. Thanks!

Comment: Any time brother! you know that big problems always come from tiny mistakes, but what matters is that you've learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the data that you are getting from local storage

```
const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked'));
```

and then, in the arrow function inside the map method, you are missing `return` the value

```
items?.map((x) => {
      console.log(x.id);
      return (x.id)
    })
```